# Store netCDF data into couchbase

Tags: python, mysql, couchbase, netcdf

I am trying to store netCDF file data into couch-base (NOSQL database) via python script. I look around on SO and google it to get some example, but I couldn't get any success.
my netCDF file or variables looks like this

```
float32 pressure(time, range)
long_name: pressure
units: m/s
yrange: [ 0.  3.]
db: 0
unlimited dimensions: time
current shape = (2809, 478)
filling off 
), 
(u'pressure', <type 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
float32 temp(time, range)
long_name: temperature
units:  
yrange: [-35.   5.]
db: 1
unlimited dimensions: time
current shape = (2809, 478)
filling off
), (u'temperature', <type 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
```

I can store netCDF data as a blob in MySQL and I am successful but I don't know how to store in NOSQL database
Can someone guide me or point out some examples how to store netCDF data into couch-base with simple example in python.

I would be grateful .

Comment: I know nothing at all about this product; however, I see that there's a Python client. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/couchbase

Answer (score 0):

Couchbase can store either JSON documents or just simple binaries directly.  Have a look at the [Start Using page on Python in the Documentation](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/sdk/python/start-using-sdk.html).  You'll also see a link to the API reference there that has more info on how upsert() can be [used with different formats](http://pythonhosted.org/couchbase/api/couchbase.html#key-and-value-format).